# Bash - command/script for getting Python's site-packages path from interpreter path

Tags: python, bash

While inside a Python virtual environment I can execute `which python` to get the path of the interpreter.

Once I get the path of the interpreter, I can find the `site-packages` library following some simple steps

1. Get the interpreter path using `which python`, this will lead to something like `/my/interp/full/path/bin/python`
2. `cd` to one level above, so we'll be at `/my/interp/full/path`
3. `cd` to `lib`, now wer'e at `/my/interp/full/path/lib`
4. Assume there is only one directory in the current directory, which will be called `python3.x`, the value of `x` depends on the version and `cd` into it, now we're at `/my/interp/full/path/lib/python3.8`
5. `site-packages` will be inside this directory

So what I'm trying to achieve is some kind of shell command/script that will use `which python` and will output the full path to the `site-packages` directory

Example of input->output:
If the output of `which python` is `/home/asdasd/zxczxc/qweqwe/bin/python`
the output should be `/home/asdasd/zxczxc/qweqwe/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`

**I'm looking for a bash solution, not Python code**

Comment: If you're not using csh, take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then; there might be a more reliable way to get the path to the program.

Comment: Generally speaking, how do you choose between multiple values of `python3.x`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller as I said, safe to assume there will be only one

Comment: At that point, can you just hard-code two `$(dirname)` steps to go up from `bin`, over to `lib`, and into `python3.*`?

Comment: I don't know, I just want some bash code to do exactly that :D You can assume in the solution that there will be only one dir, but you can't assume its exact name... it could be `python3.8` `python3.9` or other versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
pypath=/home/asdasd/zxczxc/qweqwe/bin/python
ls -ld ${pypath%bin/python}lib/python*/site-packages/
```

Comment: In order to get the exact output I wanted I dropped the `l` flag, leaving only `ls -d ${...` and it worked perfectly